# getJSON return vlaues but values not adding in list box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, getjson

i have one getJSON request which is returning proper values but its not adding in list

here is code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select#make").change(function(){
$('div.data_loading').fadeIn();
$.getJSON("getmod.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
     var options = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
     }
    $("select#vmod").html(options);
    $('div.data_loading').hide();  
   });
})  

})

</script>
```

Bellow is values returned from getmod.php

```
[{optionValue:13, optionDisplay:156},{optionValue:14, optionDisplay:164},{optionValue:15, optionDisplay:166},{optionValue:16, optionDisplay:GTV-6},{optionValue:17, optionDisplay:Spark},{optionValue:18, optionDisplay:Spider},{optionValue:19, optionDisplay:Graduate},{optionValue:20, optionDisplay:Quadrifoglio},{optionValue:21, optionDisplay:Milano},]
```

here is select box

```
<select name="vmod" id="vmod" >
</select>
```

bellow is my php file which return JSON

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="select mname,mod from modl where mkd=".$id;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "["; 
for($i=1;$i<=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "{optionValue:".$row['mod'].", optionDisplay:". $row['mname']."}";
echo ",";
}
echo "]";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript code looks ok.

Is this the exact response form the server? Then your JSON is not valid. String values and keys have to be enclosed in **double quotes** (I'm also not sure about the trailing comma). Paste your JSON [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/) and test it. Also have a look at http://json.org/.

This would be valid:

```
[{"optionValue":13, optionDisplay:156},
 {"optionValue":16, "optionDisplay":"GTV-6"}]
```

It pretty much looks like you built the JSON string manually (using string concatenation and a loop). Don't do that,  use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

**Update:** Here is how it should be:

```
$results = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

---

Also note that your code is prone to SQL injection attacks. You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on `$_GET['id']`. Or better, use prepared statements.